# PHP Compare 2 path strings and return the unique portion

Tags: php, string, path, unique, string-comparison

I have disappointingly searched almost everywhere, but couldn't find any reliable function(neither built-in nor user-defined) in PHP, which could compare two paths (regardless of the OS and path separator differences) and return the actual difference i.e. the unique string between 2 paths.

The 2 paths that I wanna compare are below:

```
[site_root]\public\module\wysiwyg/
[site_root]\
```

And post comparison, I want the output to be:

```
public\module\wysiwyg/
```

I have checked out `substr` and `strcmp` but those only can return the integer values determining whether one string is longer/shorter than the other.

Can anyone help figuring out method for path comparison ?

Comment: If the two paths are /1/2/3 and /1/A/3, what's the output you expect? Are you assuming that one path is always a *prefix* of the other?

Comment: Yes the two paths will mostly have some string in common. It could be prefix/suffix

Comment: Is your real goal to figure out relative/absolute differences in paths? For instance, given a known absolute, and provided relative, create a new path that is the minimal representative of the combination?

Comment: The reason I ask is that there is a [wonderful library](https://github.com/webmozart/path-util) out there that has a lot of methods specific to paths including `Path::getLongestCommonBasePath(array)`, `Path::makeRelative(string, string) and `Path::makeAbsolute(relative, absolute)`

Comment: I am kinda looking for specifically core PHP solution, whether in-built or user-made, but I don't need to require any external library for the same.

Comment: What if the external library is a user-made solution using "core PHP", would that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried that is not reliable? At first glance this could be accomplished by normalizing the directory separators, converting to an array, then using `array_diff` to compare the paths:

```
//list of directory separaters
$normalizeDirectorySeparator = array('\\', '/', ':');

//our paths to compare
$path1 = '[site_root]\public\module\wysiwyg/';
$path2 = '[site_root]\\';

//normalize directory separators
$path1 = str_replace($normalizeDirectorySeparator, '/', $path1);
$path2 = str_replace($normalizeDirectorySeparator, '/', $path2);

//convert to array
$path1Arr = explode('/', $path1);
$path2Arr = explode('/', $path2);

//get differences
$diff = array_diff($path1Arr, $path2Arr);

//output differences
echo implode('/', $diff); /* public/module/wysiwyg */
```

Comment: Can you show how to handle a match, if the two `$path1Arr` === `$path2Arr`? Specifically, I need to match on the full path with filename.

Comment: @ScottFleming I would just do a string comparison after normalizing the directory separators: `if ($path1 === $path2) { echo 'matches'; } else { $path1Arr = explode ........ }`

Answer (score 0):

Symfony has cool functions:

```
Path::getLongestCommonBasePath(
    '/var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/config/config.yaml',
    '/var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/config/routing.yaml',
    '/var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/config/services.yaml',
    '/var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/images/banana.gif',
    '/var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/uploads/images/nicer-banana.gif'
);
// => /var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs
```

and

```
Path::isBasePath("/var/www", "/var/www/project");
// => true

Path::isBasePath("/var/www", "/var/www/project/..");
// => true

Path::isBasePath("/var/www", "/var/www/project/../..");
// => false
```

Documentation:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html#finding-longest-common-base-paths

Source code:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.1/src/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Path.php#method_isBasePath